# Commons method to test for an empty Java object graph?

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, utilities

I've found myself writing a method like this:

```
boolean isEmpty(MyStruct myStruct) {
  return (myStruct.getStringA() == null || myStruct.getStringA().isEmpty())
    && (myStruct.getListB() == null || myStruct.getListB().isEmpty());
}
```

And then imagine this struct with lots of other properties and other nested lists, and you can imagine that this method gets very big and is tightly coupled to the data model.

Does Apache Commons, or Spring, or some other FOSS utility have the ability to recursively reflectively walk an object graph and determine that it's basically devoid of any useful data, other than the holders for Lists, Arrays, Maps, and such?  So that I can just write:

```
boolean isEmpty(MyStruct myStruct) {
  return MagicUtility.isObjectEmpty(myStruct);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Vladimir for pointing me in the right direction (I gave you an upvote!) although my solution uses `PropertyUtils` rather than `BeanUtils`

I did have to implement it but it wasn't hard.  Here's the solution.  I only did it for Strings and Lists since that's all I happen to have at the moment.  Could be extended for Maps and Arrays.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class ObjectUtils {

  /**
   * Tests an object for logical emptiness. An object is considered logically empty if its public gettable property
   * values are all either null, empty Strings or Strings with just whitespace, or lists that are either empty or
   * contain only other logically empty objects.  Currently does not handle Maps or Arrays, just Lists.
   * 
   * @param object
   *          the Object to test
   * @return whether object is logically empty
   * 
   * @author Kevin Pauli
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static boolean isObjectEmpty(Object object) {

    // null
    if (object == null) {
      return true;
    }

    // String
    else if (object instanceof String) {
      return StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim((String) object));
    }

    // List
    else if (object instanceof List) {
      boolean allEntriesStillEmpty = true;
      final Iterator<Object> iter = ((List) object).iterator();
      while (allEntriesStillEmpty && iter.hasNext()) {
        final Object listEntry = iter.next();
        allEntriesStillEmpty = isObjectEmpty(listEntry);
      }
      return allEntriesStillEmpty;
    }

    // arbitrary Object
    else {
      try {
        boolean allPropertiesStillEmpty = true;
        final Map<String, Object> properties = PropertyUtils.describe(object);
        final Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = properties.entrySet().iterator();
        while (allPropertiesStillEmpty && iter.hasNext()) {
          final Entry<String, Object> entry = iter.next();
          final String key = entry.getKey();
          final Object value = entry.getValue();

          // ignore the getClass() property
          if ("class".equals(key))
            continue;

          allPropertiesStillEmpty = isObjectEmpty(value);
        }
        return allPropertiesStillEmpty;
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can combine Appache Common `StringUtils.isEmpty()` method with `BeanUtils.getProperties()`.

Comment: I don't see a method BeanUtils.getProperties(), at least in v 1.8.3 of BeanUtils...  http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Okay, I tried this, and it works for String properties but not for nested structures.  The reason is that The BeanUtils.describe() and BeanUtils.getProperty() methods return the String representation of the object, rather than the object itself.  Thanks anyway...

Comment: I just discovered the PropertyUtils class, which does return me the real object, and I have arrived at a solution.  Thanks for your help!  Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Kevin, Haven't seen anything like the method you asked for (interested in it myself as well), however, have you considered using reflection to query your object on runtime?

Comment: Yeah I could do that but the point is I don't want to waste my employer's time reinventing the wheel... this smells like a problem that has likely been solved already by some nice person.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a library that does this, but using reflection, it is not too hard to implement by yourself.
You can easily loop over getter methods of a class and decide whether the instance has a value set, you can further decide the outcome depending on the getter's return type.

The hard part is to define which members of a class you consider being "useful data". Just leaving out Lists, Maps and Arrays probably won't get you far.

I would actually consider writing your own Annotation type in order to "mark" the appropiate "useful" members (which could then be noticed+handled by the reflection code). I don't know if this is an elegant approach to your problem, since I don't know how many classes are affected.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't sound hard, actually sounds fun but I want to be nice to other people on my team and future developers, and a well documented API that is already tested and widely used and performs this very basic cross-domain task would be highly preferable to a custom solution.

Comment: I totally agree to that. Would to the same, even though implementing this by myself would be fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really imagine a situation where something completely devoid of any content in a whole object graph would get in to an application. Furthermore, what exactly would be considered "empty"? Would that just refer to strings and collections? Would a string with only whitespace count? What about numbers... would any number make the object non-empty, or would specific numbers like -1 count as empty? As yet another issue, it doesn't seem like it'd generally be useful to know if there is NO content in an object... typically you need to ensure that specific fields have specific data, etc. There are too many possibilities for some general method like this to make sense, in my opinion.

Maybe a more complete validation system like [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) would work better. The reference implementation for that is [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Comment: HOW it got there is another question entirely.  But it is there (oh yes, it's there), it is big, and I need to know if it is logically empty.  As for the questions you ask about (whitespace, arrays lists, etc.) I would expect that a decent, mature utility would provide parameters to allow me to control those things.  But a reasonable default implementation would not require the parameters, and would work the way I need it to (treating "" as empty, or empty lists, arrays and maps as empty).  JSR-303 seems like overkill for this.  But thanks for the response...

Comment: @Kevin: I think it boils down to this requirement not being as common as you think, perhaps. As far as I know, there's nothing built specifically for this.

Answer (score 0):

Although none of the above utility methods can be generic. The only way (to my knowledge) is to compare with a empty object. Create a instance of the object (with no properties set) and use ".equals" method to compare. Make sure that equals is properly implemented to true for 2 equal non empty objects & true for 2 empty objects.